# Spring 3 @PathVariable validation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, bean-validation

What is the proper way to validate a **@PathVariable** argument? This is not working:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Foo getFoo(@Valid @Min(1) @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
```

There is no Exception, it's simply ignored.

I'm using **spring 3.2.3.RELEASE** and **hibernate-validator 5.0.0.Final**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This doesn't seem to be currently supported.](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6380)

Validation is meant for beans and a `Long` object is not a bean, especially coming from the URL.

The alternative is to do your own validation within the handler method.